# time series from list of dates-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, count

I have a list of dates **(ListA)** each entry in which represents an occurrence. How do I make a time series out of the list in python3?  A sequence of dates would be on the X axis, and the frequency of each date would be on the Y

```
ListA = [2016-04-05, 2016-04-05, 2016-04-07, 2016-09-10, 
         2016-03-05, 2016-07-11, 2017-01-01]
```

Desired Output:

```
[2016-04-05, 2], [2016-04-06, 0], [2016-04-07, 1],
[2016-04-08, 0], ……………… .., [2017-01-01, 1]
```

Desired Format of output:

```
[[Date, Frequency],....,*]
```

I have the *Date* code as:

```
Date=pd.date_range('2016-04-05', '2017-01-01', freq='D')
Print(Date)
```

Which gives:

> [2016-04-05, 2016-04-06, 2016-04-07,....,]

I need something like the code below to step through *Date* above to get the *frequency* for each date.

```
for item in ListA:
    if item>=Date[0] and item<Date[1]:
        print(ListA.count(item))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the `collections` module this is very straight forward:

**Code:**

```
dates = [
    '2016-04-05',
    '2016-04-05',
    '2016-04-07',
    '2016-09-10',
    '2016-03-05',
    '2016-07-11',
    '2017-01-01'
]

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(dates)
print(sorted(counts.items()))
```

**Results:**

```
[('2016-03-05', 1), ('2016-04-05', 2), 
 ('2016-04-07', 1), ('2016-07-11', 1), 
 ('2016-09-10', 1), ('2017-01-01', 1)]
```

**Build a list over `pandas.DatetimeIndex`:**

To build a list of lists over a range of dates is easy enough because a `Counter` will return `0` when indexed with a value for which the count is zero.

```
# pandas date range
dates = pd.date_range('2016-04-05', '2017-01-01', freq='D')

# counter for date we need counted
counts = Counter(pd.to_datetime(dates))

# build a list using a list comprehension of counts at all dates in range
date_occurence_sequence = [[d, counts[d]] for d in dates]
```

**Add to per day dataframe:**

And since you seem to be using `pandas` let's insert the occurrence counts into a data frame indexed per day.

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.date_range('2016-04-05', '2017-01-01', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame([0] * len(index), index=index)
df.update(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Counter(pd.to_datetime(dates)), 'index'))

print(df.head())
```

**Results:**

```
              0
2016-04-05  2.0
2016-04-06  0.0
2016-04-07  1.0
2016-04-08  0.0
2016-04-09  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen for that module. The thing is it needs to count the dates that have no occurrences like [2016-04-06, 0]. I guess I can append the time series dates to the ListA, do the Counter, then subtract them all by 1.

Comment: Since you had a `pandas` function in some of your example, I added some `pandas` code to get your desired zero occurrences.